# How to reliably and quickly get the MAC address of a network card given its device instance ID

Tags: c++, windows, networking, wmi, device-instance-id

Given a [device instance ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541327%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for a network card, I would like to know its MAC address.  Example device instance ID on my system for integrated Intel Gigabit card:

```
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_10CC&SUBSYS_00008086&REV_00\3&33FD14CA&0&C8
```

So far, the algorithm I have used works as follows:

1. Call [`SetupDiGetClassDevs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE`.
2. Call [`SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551010%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the returned device in a [`SP_DEVINFO_DATA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552344%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
3. Call [`SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551015%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `GUID_NDIS_LAN_CLASS` to get a device interface.
4. Call [`SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551120%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for this returned device interface.  This gets us the device path as a string:  `\\?\pci#ven_8086&dev_10cc&subsys_00008086&rev_00#3&33fd14ca&0&c8#{ad498944-762f-11d0-8dcb-00c04fc3358c}\{28fd5409-15bd-4c06-b62f-004d3a06f852}`
5. At this point we have an address to the network card driver's interface.  Open it with [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) using the result from #4.
6. Call [`DeviceIoControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with [`IOCTL_NDIS_QUERY_GLOBAL_STATS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548975%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and OID of [`OID_802_3_PERMANENT_ADDRESS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff569074%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the MAC address.

This usually works, and has been used successfully on quite a large number of machines.  However, it appears that a very select few machines have network drivers that aren't responding properly to the `DeviceIoControl` request in step #6; the problem persists even after updating network card drivers to the latest.  These are newer, Windows 7-based computers.  Specifically, `DeviceIoControl` completes successfully, but returns zero bytes instead of the expected six bytes containing the MAC address.

A clue seems to be on the MSDN page for [`IOCTL_NDIS_QUERY_GLOBAL_STATS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548975%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> This IOCTL will be deprecated in later operating system releases. You
>   should use WMI interfaces to query miniport driver information. For
>   more information see, NDIS Support for WMI.

-- perhaps newer network card drivers are no longer implementing this IOCTL?

So, how should I get this working?  Is it possible there's an oversight in my approach and I'm doing something slightly wrong?  Or do I need to take a much more different approach?  Some alternate approaches seem to include:

- Query [`Win32_NetworkAdapter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI class: provides needed information but rejected due to horrible performance.  See [Fast replacement for Win32_NetworkAdapter WMI class for getting MAC address of local computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322253/fast-replacement-for-win32-networkadapter-wmi-class-for-getting-mac-address-of-l)
- Query `MSNdis_EthernetPermanentAddress` WMI class: appears to be the WMI replacement for `IOCTL_NDIS_QUERY_GLOBAL_STATS` and queries the OID directly from the driver - and this one works on the troublesome network driver.  Unfortunately, the returned class instances only provide the MAC address and the `InstanceName`, which is a localized string like `Intel(R) 82567LM-2 Gigabit Network Connection`.  Querying `MSNdis_EnumerateAdapter` yields a list which relates the `InstanceName` to a `DeviceName`, like `\DEVICE\{28FD5409-15BD-4C06-B62F-004D3A06F852}`.  I'm not sure how to go from the `DeviceName` to the plug-and-play device instance ID (`PCI\VEN_8086......`).
- Call [`GetAdaptersAddresses`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`GetAdaptersInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365917%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (deprecated).  The only non-localized identifier I can find in the return value is the adapter name, which is a string like `{28FD5409-15BD-4C06-B62F-004D3A06F852}` - same as the `DeviceName` returned by the WMI NDIS classes.  So again, I can't figure out how to relate it to the device instance ID.  I'm not sure if it would work 100% of the time either - e.g. for adapters without TCP/IP protocol configured.
- NetBIOS method: requires specific protocols to be set up on the card so won't work 100% of time.  Generally seems hack-ish, and not a way to relate to device instance ID anyway that I know of.  I'd reject this approach.
- UUID generation method: rejected for reasons I won't elaborate on here.

It seems like if I could find a way to get the "GUID" for the card from the device instance ID, I'd be well on my way with one of the remaining two ways of doing things.  But I haven't figured out how yet.  Otherwise, the WMI NDIS approach would seem most promising.

Getting a list of network cards and MAC addresses is easy, and there are several ways of doing it.  Doing it in a fast way that lets me relate it to the device instance ID is apparently hard...

**EDIT:**  Sample code of the IOCTL call if it helps anyone (ignore the leaked hFile handle):

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(dosDevice.c_str(), 0, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    DWORD err = GetLastError();
    wcout << "GetMACAddress: CreateFile on " << dosDevice << " failed." << endl;
    return MACAddress();
}
BYTE address[6];
DWORD oid = OID_802_3_PERMANENT_ADDRESS, returned = 0;
//this fails too: DWORD oid = OID_802_3_CURRENT_ADDRESS, returned = 0;
if (!DeviceIoControl(hFile, IOCTL_NDIS_QUERY_GLOBAL_STATS, &oid, sizeof(oid), address, 6, &returned, NULL)) {
    DWORD err = GetLastError();
    wcout << "GetMACAddress: DeviceIoControl on " << dosDevice << " failed." << endl;
    return MACAddress();
}
if (returned != 6) {
    wcout << "GetMACAddress: invalid address length of " << returned << "." << endl;
    return MACAddress();
}
```

The code fails, printing:

```
GetMACAddress: invalid address length of 0.
```

So the DeviceIoControl returns non-zero indicating success, but then returns zero bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wound up using `SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty` to read `SPDRP_FRIENDLYNAME`.  If that's not found, then I read `SPDRP_DEVICEDESC` instead.  Ultimately, this gets me a string like "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2".  I then match this against the InstanceName property in the WMI NDIS classes (`MSNdis_EthernetPermanentAddress` WMI class).  Both properties must be read in case there are multiple adapters sharing the same driver (i.e. "#2", "#3", etc.) - if there's only one adapter then `SPDRP_FRIENDLYNAME` isn't available, but if there is more than one then `SPDRP_FRIENDLYNAME` is required to differentiate them.

The method makes me a little nervous because I'm comparing what seems like a localized string, and there's no documentation that I've found that guarantees what I'm doing will always work.  Unfortunately, I haven't found any better ways that are documented to work, either.

A couple other alternate methods involve groveling in undocumented registry locations.  One method is spencercw's method, and the other would be to read `SPDRP_DRIVER`, which is the name of a subkey under `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class`.  Underneath the driver key, look for the `Linkage\Export` value which then seems like it could be matched to the `DeviceName` property of the `MSNdis_EnumerateAdapter` class.  But there's no documentation I could find that says these values can be legally matched.  Furthermore, the only documentation I found about `Linkage\Export` was from the Win2000 registry reference and explicitly said that applications shouldn't rely on it.

Another method would be to look at my original question, step 4:  "`SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail` for this returned device interface".  The device interface path actually can be used to reconstruct the device path.  Start with device interface path: `\\?\pci#ven_8086&dev_10cc&subsys_00008086&rev_00#3&33fd14ca&0&c8#{ad498944-762f-11d0-8dcb-00c04fc3358c}\{28fd5409-15bd-4c06-b62f-004d3a06f852}`.  Then, remove everything before the final slash, leaving you with: `{28fd5409-15bd-4c06-b62f-004d3a06f852}`.  Finally, prepend `\Device\` to this string and match it against the WMI NDIS classes.  Again, however, this seems to be undocumented and relying on an implementation detail of a device interface path.

In the end, the other methods I investigated had their own undocumented complications that sounded at least as serious as matching the `SPDRP_FRIENDLYNAME` / `SPDRP_DEVICEDESC` strings.  So I opted for the simpler approach, which was to just match those strings against the WMI NDIS classes.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way to do it:

1. Call [`GetAdaptersAddresses`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365915%28VS.85%29.aspx) to get a list of [`IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366058%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structs
2. Iterate over each adapter and get its GUID from the `AdapterName` field (I'm not sure if this behaviour is guaranteed, but all the adapters in my system have a GUID here, and the documentation says the `AdapterName` is permanent)
3. For each adapter read the registry key from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Network\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\<the adapter GUID>\Connection\PnPInstanceID` (if it exists) (got this idea from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/630d7583-a003-471b-8a41-6b8e4cc06c75); searching on Google that key seems to be well documented, so it's not likely to change)
4. From this key you get the device ID for the adapter (something like: `PCI\VEN_14E4&DEV_16B1&SUBSYS_96B11849&REV_10\4&2B8260C3&0&00E4`)
5. Do this for each adapter until you find a match. When you get your match just go back to the `IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES` and look at the `PhysicalAddress` field
6. Get a beer (optional)

It wouldn't be Windows if there weren't a million ways to do something!

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want to get the MAC address in order to implement some sort of DRM, inventory, or classification system, since you tried to get the *permanent* MAC address instead of the current one.

You seem to forget that there's even an *administratively super-imposed MAC address* (in other words: a "forced" MAC address).
Some drivers let you do this from the Device Property page, under the Advanced tab (for example: my Marvell network adapter let me do this), while some others don't let you do that (read: they don't support that property).

However, it all ends in a Registry value: `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\xxxx\NetworkAddress`, with a `REG_SZ` type.
Here you can set a different MAC address than the original one, in the form "01020304abcd" (6 bytes, plain hexadecimal, without `:` separators or `0x` prefix).
After you set it, reboot the machine, and on power-up the new MAC address will have effect.

I happen to have a motherboard with two Marvell integrated NICs, and a NETGEAR USB WiFi NIC. The Marvell one supports changing the MAC address: if you set the `NetworkAddress` value in the Registry, you see the new value in the driver properties page, too, and it has effect immediately, without the need to restart (if you change it from device Property Page).
Here follows the results of reading the MAC address with different methods:

- `GetAdaptersInfo`: new MAC address
- `IOCTL_NDIS_QUERY_GLOBAL_STATS`: original MAC address
- `MSNdis_EthernetPermanentAddress`: original MAC address

I tried adding the `NetworkAddress` value in the Registry for the NETGEAR USB WiFi NIC, and the results are:

- `GetAdaptersInfo`: new MAC address
- `IOCTL_NDIS_QUERY_GLOBAL_STATS`: new MAC address
- `MSNdis_EthernetPermanentAddress`: new MAC address

**The original MAC addres is gone.**

So, in order to not be fooled by a "malicious" user, you always need to check the `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\xxxx\NetworkAddress` Registry value. If that is set, i guess it's better to *not trust that Network Adapter at all*, since it is up to the driver implementation to decide what will be presented to you using the different methods.

Some background for getting to that Registry key:

[Microsoft documentation about the HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Class key](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/drivers/install/hklm-system-currentcontrolset-control-registry-tree)
According to the Microsoft documentation on that page,

> There is a subkey for each class that is named using the GUID of the
>   setup class

So we choose the `{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}` subkey (aka `GUID_DEVCLASS_NET`, defined in `<devguid.h>`, and further documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/drivers/install/system-defined-device-setup-classes-available-to-vendors#network-adapter-))

Again, according to Microsoft documentation,

> Each class subkey contains other subkeys known as software keys (or, driver keys) for each device instance of that class installed in the system. Each of these software keys is named by using a device instance ID, which is a base-10, four-digit ordinal value
>   The *xxxx* part is a 4-character textual representation of a positive integer, starting from 0

So, you can traverse the subkeys up from 0000, 0001, 0002, up to the number of network adapters in your system.
The documentation stops here: I didn't find any other documentation about the different registry values, or such.

However, in each of these subkeys, you can find REG_SZ values that can help you link the `GetAdaptersInfo()`, `MSNdis_EthernetPermanentAddress`, `Win32_NetworkAdapter`, and Device Instance ID worlds (and this answers your question).

The Registry values are:

- `DeviceInstanceID`: its value is, no surprise, the Device Instance ID
- `NetCfgInstanceId`: its value is the `AdapterName` member of the `IP_ADAPTER_INFO` struct, returned by `GetAdaptersInfo()`. It is also the `GUID` member of the `Win32_NetworkAdapter` WMI class.
- Don't forget the `NetworkAddress` one: should a valid MAC address exist here, a driver *may* report it as the MAC address in use by `GetAdaptersInfo()`, `MSNdis_EthernetPermanentAddress`, and `IOCTL_NDIS_QUERY_GLOBAL_STATS`!

Then, as you already said, the only connection between the `MSNdis_EthernetPermanentAddress` WMI Class and the rest of the "world" is by its `InstanceName` member. You can relate it to the `Description` member of the `IP_ADAPTER_INFO` struct, returned by `GetAdaptersInfo()`. Although it may be a localized name, it seems to be unique for the system (For my two integrated Marvell NICs, the second one has a " #2" appended to its name).

### Final note:

Said all the above, [the user could choose to disable WMI...](https://superuser.com/q/1265954/739197)