# getmac ERROR: Invalid Class (Windows 8.1)

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, command-prompt, mac-address

When trying to run `getmac` from the Windows Command Prompt, I am getting "ERROR: Invalid class". As a Windows utility, I'm not entirely sure why it's broken or how to go about fixing it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

----- EDIT -----

The point of this exercise it to be able to programmatically acccess a user's MAC address from a Node.js application. I originally ran into the issue with the [getmac](https://www.npmjs.com/package/getmac) node module, which uses `getmac` under the hood. Thus I can't use Powershell or some other suggested solutions -- and I need this to be able to work offline.

Comment: Yes, `getmac` is a Windows utility: http://superuser.com/questions/66988/how-do-i-locate-the-mac-address-of-my-computer

Comment: Is this a virtual machine? Does `getmac /v /fo list` still error out?

Comment: Not a VM, an Acer PC running Windows 8.1 -- and yes, I get the same `Invalid class` error running that command

Comment: Is there a getmac.exe file in the `c:\Windows\System32` folder?

Comment: @paaschpa I get the impression it's there but something's disrupting access to the WMI information that (I'm guessing) `getmac` uses.

Comment: @arthurakay Do you need programmatic access to the MAC address, or do you just need to look it up for something e.g. licence registration? Could you use the C# code in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7322670/1738) to get the MAC address?

Comment: @philpursglove I think you're right and would expect the 'not recognized as  command' error if it wasn't, but just making sure.

Answer (score 2):

use ipconfig and use the physical address or in powershell use Get-NetAdapter

Comment: I believe you would need to use `ipconfig /all` to include the 'Physical/Mac Address' with the resulting data.

Comment: `ipconfig /all` seems to give me what I need... when I'm offline, it does indeed still show me the physical address. Now I just need to parse that out :-)